# How to write a script that takes two arguments lower bound and upper bound and displays the file sizes who are in that specific range?

Tags: linux, awk, scripting

This script has to be done utilizing the awk command. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am a newbie and trying to figure this out. If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

This is my attempt so far:

```
read $0
read $1
ls -l|awk '{/$0/, /$1/} {print $5 "\t" $9}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`, rules consist of a pattern and a command which is executed if the pattern matches the record. Commands are delimited with brackets, patterns are not. And the range pattern does not work anything like you seem to think it does. Using a regular expression to match is not going to help much, since you are interested in numerical values in a given range. If your range were 10 to 20, for example, 15 would not match the lower bound, but would still be in range.